# What's the keyboard shortcut to view branches modal screen in WebStorm in macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm

Is there a keyboard shortcut for this screen?

This modal is opened when you click on the git icon on the bottom right corner.
In windows, you can open this screen by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

You can check what shortcut is assigned to **Main menu | VCS | Git | Branches...** action in **Preferences | Keymap**